# DataSet to SQL mapping framework?

Tags: .net, sql, mapping

I'm developing a system that needs to accept sql queries dynamically.  I'm looking for something where someone can define a select query in a file external to the system -- the system would execute the query and return the results as a DataSet. Then the system would read a mapping file (also defined external to the system) that would tell it how to save the data.  I just wanted to make sure there wasn't any existing framework that I could piggyback off of before went ahead and implemented the functionality myself.

Comment: Just to be clear, the relational struction between source (DataSet) and destination (SQL table) are not the same.  This is why I need to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataAdapter` class and related classes already have this. See [`TableMappings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.tablemappings.aspx).